# Mapping elements in vector to related, but larger vector

Tags: matlab

I need some help to map elements from a short vector to a larger vector in Matlab. I can do this with a for-loop, but I'm sure there's a way to avoid this.

I have input vectors of same size: A = [ 2 3 5 ] and B = [ 0.1 0.3 0.23 ]. Vector A contains "index" and vector B data. A third input vector is given as C = [ 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 5 5 ] and now I want to generate the vector D = [ 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.23 0.23 ].

How can I, in Matlab, generate vector D, without using for-loops?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements of the index vector are positive integers you can just use indexing:

```
idx(A,1) = 1:numel(A);
D = B(idx(C));
```

If `A` contains positive integers of large values you can use sparse matrix:

```
idx = sparse(A,1,1:numel(A));
D = B(idx(C));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A = [2 3 5];
B = [0.1 0.3 0.23];
C = [2 2 2 3 3 3 3 5 5];
```

Use the second output of [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to create an index vector:

```
[~, ind] = ismember(C, A);
D = B(ind);
```

Alternatively, use [`interp1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html):

```
D = interp1(A, B, C);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to look up the index of each element in `C`, assuming that the values correspond to exactly the values in `A`. If `A` is not sorted then we have to sort the items of `B` first in order to match the indexing given by `unique`:

```
A = [2 3 5];
B = [0.1 0.3 0.23];
C = [2 2 2 3 3 3 3 5 5];

[~,isort] = sort(A);
Bsort = B(isort);    % sorted according to A
[~,~,k] = unique(C); % indices of items in C to pick from A
D = Bsort(k);        % each matching element from (sorted) B
```